# Making a program using a GUI and MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, swing, user-interface

i have a question regarding a program i am working on. It`s a database manager for a MqSQL db , written in Java. So i have the following program structure.

So i have a main class that extends JFrame, whichh is the main frame of the interface, like this (removed the unecessary code not relevant to the discussion) :

```
public class MainInterface extends JFrame {

   public MainInterface {
       ................
    MainInterface.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    MainInterface.setVisible(true);

    TopToolbar toolbar;
    try {
         toolbar = new TopToolbar();
         MainInterface.add(toolbar);
         ResultsPanel Results = new ResultsPanel();
         MainInterface.add(Results);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

TopToolbar and ResultsPanel are 2 other classes that extend JPanel, the TopToolbar class having a JToolBar with buttonsadded to it (Move Forward, MoveBack, Add entry)

```
 public class TopToolbar extends JPanel implements ActionListener {  

 TopToolBar()
 {
  //constructor in which i was adding button to the toolbar, not relevat
 }

 } 

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

     if (MoveFirst.equals(cmd)){
         try {
            DatabaseAccess disp = new DatabaseAccess();
            disp.getResults();
            int id = disp.return_id();

            System.out.println(id);

        } catch (//exceptions) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

That is the ActionListener event for the next button, which should trigger reading the next entry in the db

DatabaseAccess is another class with initializes the DB connection , and has these 2 methods :

```
public void getResults() throws SQLException {

    Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL, user, "")
    sql = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    result_set = sql.executeQuery("select * from persons");

    while (result_set.next()) {

    id = result_set.getInt(1);
    name = result_set.getString(2);

    }       

}

public int return_id(){
    return id;

}
```

The return_ID method returns (and it does work) the ID (first key in the database, will obviously add methods for the rest of the entries in the db). 
Now i want to show the ID in the final JPanel, the one called ResultsSet (just 3 JLabels and 3 TextFields for the ID , Name etc., in a GridLayout).

Since the dababase class creation (and subsequently the methods forr reading the db and returning the result) is done inside the ActionPerformed method inside the TopToolBar Jpanel, i can`t access it from the MainInterface JFrame and then use something like

```
  ResultsPanel DispResults = new ResultsPanel();
  add(DispResults);
  DispResults.setID(id_Value)
```

where setID would be a method in the ResultsPanel that uses the JTextBox setText to set the text .

Hoope i`ve managed to explain my issue as clear as i can.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your variables are correct and some are not. Be consistent if you expect people to take the time and read your code!

Comment: Whoops, didn't know that. I'm still learning. I`ll correct them ASAP. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: As duffymo has comment, you should avoid extending from `JFrame`, apart from locking your into a single use case, making it impossible to re-use you UI in other ways, you're not adding any new functionality to the frame.  Have a look at [5 Reasons to Use Composition over Inheritance in Java and OOP](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.au/2013/06/why-favor-composition-over-inheritance-java-oops-design.html) as s starting point for more details

Comment: *"i have a question"*  Great!  What is your question?  If there is an actual question buried among those words, can you add a '?' to the end of it?  If not, please think of an actual question (not a **requirement**) [edit it into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32279618/edit), and be sure to add the '?'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with several of your choices.

You should not extend JFrame.  Create a JPanel and give it to a JFrame to display.

I would dissociate the database interactions from the Swing UI.  Create them as interface-based POJOs on their own, without a UI.  Get them tested, written, and working perfectly.

Once the database interactions are perfect, give an instance of that object to the class that controls the application.  Give it a text-only interface for driving the database actions.

Once the controller is obeying every text command perfectly, using your fully tested database component, then have it create an instance of your JPanel and give it to a JFrame.  It will make the same calls to its controller owner that your text UI has already executed successfully.

Computer science is all about decomposition.  You solve big problems by breaking them into smaller ones.

If you'd like to see a great example of what your app might look like, download [SQL Squirrel](http://www.squirrelsql.org/).

Comment: Not sure how, except to point out that there's no way the subclass overrides or extends the existing behavior.  It's knowing that inheritance isn't always necessary - composition is often a better option.  it is in this case.

Comment: Much more than opinion, but I don't care whether you or the OP accept it or not.  I don't have to prove that decomposition is a good way to solve problems.

Comment: Please, offer us your proof so we can see how it's done.  Or do you just comment without ever putting yourself out there?

Comment: You're proof that reading, thinking on, and understanding the points is sufficient.  Please demonstrate the proof you continue to insist on.  I don't think it can be proven except by experience.

Comment: Then forgive me for trying to help

Comment: I fail to see how hectoring comments is "trying to help".   Do you tell Jon Skeet to provide proof plus citations that contradict his advice?  If not, then stop imposing your unreasonable requirements on me.  Again you miss the opportunity - please type that proof at length so we can all see and judge.  I'll wait.

Comment: I'm not sure what proof you're asking for? You've made a bold statement about not doing something, something I agree with and as an experience developer, understand, but the OP doesn't have such benefit.  You've mentioned composition over inheritance, which is an absolutely awesome point, that alone would be enough to add weight to your comment, which would further support your suggestion of de-coupling the code.  if you don't want to, then don't, I just thought it would make a good answer into a great answer, that's all

Comment: Funny how you removed all your comments.  I was going to cite your request for that proof.  You must be ashamed of yourself to have to remove them.  Please stop worrying about my answers; look to your own.  If you have a great answer, give it and we'll all up or down vote as we see fit.

Comment: FYI: I removed them because they were adding noise and I didn't want to clutter the comments as it was obvious your weren't interest in some friendly feedback, again, sorry for bothering you

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for the input (and sorry for the late reply). I managed to get everything up and running following your tips. Made the database interface as POJOs and and put the GUI inside a single JPanel which is given to a JFrame for display(with 2 additional JPanel classes for the pop-up windows required for entering a new entryy in the dabase or deleting one searched by name). Also thanks for the links regarding compositions versus inheritance, i`ll have a look at them today. I`ll mark this one as answered. thanks a lot again